# Git hangs on writing objects and more

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and when I try to push more than one file to Github, git hangs either on writing objects (if the package has so many files) or on after writing objects (if the package has less files - like 10-15). I tried to recreate the git file but it did not work. I tried using `openssh-server` and configured sshd_config to have "TcpRcvBufPoll no" on itself (by the way, it did not have this phrase initially, I added it as a new line), it did not work either. What could be the problem? I cannot push even 10-15 files at once. It's the initial commit and I can't work it out.

Comment: can you share .git/config file? you can hide your private information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a git remote via HTTPS and confirming that the behaviour is only due to broken SSH configuration?

```
git remote add myrepoHTTP https://github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Comment: I've added this, but the behavior is the same. Do I have to execute any more command for this to take effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning your existing repository using HTTPS and pushing files that way.

Follow the setup as described on [github](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) to setup git and github to work on HTTPS.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: Well, I did not clone it actually. I basically removed the old one and create a new remote over https.

Comment: So can you pull from the remote?

Comment: Yes, exactly. After I pulled from the remote, I added my own files, then commited them. Last, I tried to push, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question, but I ran into a similar problem, upload freezed at 71% and hope my solution can help anyone finding this ;)

My problem was that I created the directory and git-repository with superuser, so the push failed cause it was freezing at around 70%. Chowning the directory to the designated git-ssh-user solved the problem.